# iOS and Android wifi probe

Tags: android, iphone, wifi, probe

i'd like to know if someone can explain me how IOS & Android work when they have wifi on & they are in standby mode.

I have tried myself to do some tests but i get different results, for example.

IOS:

- when in standby there is a probe every 15 minutes for 2/3 minutes. After those 2/3 minutes it waits for other 15 minutes and starts over.

Android:

- a probe every 10 minutes and lasts for 2/3 minutes. As above, after 10 minutes it starts over again.

The strange behaviour i have noticed is that the RSSI is very very low, like -80 or so.

Does anyone know exactly the algorythm that is behind the scenes?

Thanks.